# How is mx:DataService in LCDS different from Flash Builder 4 DCD data features?

Tags: apache-flex, coldfusion, flex4, blazeds, lcds

LCDS Data Management via `<mx:DataService>` (only available with `fds.swc` from LCDS) can do pagination and data sync, but FlashBuilder 4 + Flex4 can do them as well!  See the following Flex4 + FlashBuilder 4 tutorials:

- [Manage the access of data through **paging**](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flex/4.0/FlexTutorials/WSbde04e3d3e6474c43c24c72e1215f92c9b6-8000.html)
- [Using Data Management to **Synchronize** Data Updates](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flex/4.0/FlexTutorials/WSbde04e3d3e6474c4292a0331216558354b-8000.html)

How do these 2 data management features differ in LCDS vs FB4+Flex4 specifically?  Are there anything LCDS Data Management can do that Flex4+FB4 Data Management can't?

Are these features in FB4 client-side data management?

- Conflict resolution?  LCDS has some
  conflict resolution support, does FB4
  data management handles that?
- Real
  time Grid updates?  Is the grid
  automatically updated on all clients,
  when BlazeDS is used as the data
  provider / endpoint?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I blogged about this exact topic : http://quetwo.com/2010/02/18/flash-builder-client-side-data-management-vs-lcds/

To quickly answer your question :

LCDS can provide Conflict Resolution.  Client-Side cannot.
LCDS can provide real-time grid updates, Client-side cannot.

Answer (score 1):

Supported in LCDS but not with the client-side data management in Flex 4 / FB4:

- Notifications to other clients when changes are made on the server (optionally real-time in LCDS)
- Conflict resolution
- Lazy loading of associations
- Model-driven development